# Getting error while developing a module in admin related to grid in magento

Tags: gridview

Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magentoNew/app/code/local/Pfay/Test/Block/Adminhtml/Test/Edit/Tabs.php on line 23

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution for the above question.

Solution:

Just convert the case of first letter of files from lower to upper.
For example : form.php to Form.php, edit.php to Edit.php

In my case changes are to be done for below mentioned files:

1. app\code\local\Pfay\Test\Block\Adminhtml\Test
   edit.php to Edit.php
2. app\code\local\Pfay\Test\Block\Adminhtml\Test\Edit
   form.php to Form.php
3. app\code\local\Pfay\Test\Block\Adminhtml\Test\Edit\Tab
   form.php to Form.php

Here Pfay is the namespace and test is the module